# Values of an array not comparing to numbers correctly

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Im trying to get an array from grades.txt, and determine what letter grade it should be assigned.

I either get

```
hw4part2.sh: line 26: [: : integer expression expected
```

If i use -ge or

```
hw4part2.sh: line 26: [: : unary operator expected
```

If i use >=

Below is the code im trying to get working

```
mapfile -t scores < grades.txt

numOScores=0
numOA=0
numOB=0
numOC=0
numOD=0
numOF=0
DoneWScores=0
A=90
B=80
C=70
D=60
F=59


while [ $DoneWScores -eq 0 ]
do

numOScores=$((numOScores + 1)) 



if [ "${scores[$numOScores]}" -ge "$A" ]
then
    echo "A"
elif [ "${scores[$numOScores]}" -ge "$B" ]
then
    echo "B"
elif [ "${scores[$numOScores]}" -ge "$C" ]
then
    echo "C"
elif [ "${scores[$numOScores]}" -ge "$D" ]
then
    echo "D"
elif [ "${scores[$numOScores]}" -le "$F" ]
then
    echo "F"
else 
    echo "Done/error"
    DoneWScores=1
fi

done
```

If anyone knows what my problem is, that'd be greatly appreciated

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: That's an interesting way to iterate through an array. Why not a for loop?

Comment: At least one problem is how you're iterating over the `scores` array. Say there are 5 scores, so the array index runs from 0 to 4. The loop will run through the tests in the `if` and `elif` conditions for `numOScores` from 1 to 5, missing the first entry and getting errors on the fifth (nonexistent) entry.

Comment: The immediate problem, as already pointed out in a previous comment, is that you are reading past the end of the array. But more fundamentally, why are you using Bash for this task at all? It's quite natural and succinct e.g. in Awk.

Comment: to continue Gordon's comment, the problem when $numOScrores == 5, is that ${scores[$numOScores]} is empty, and `[` sees `[ "" -ge 90 ]` and the empty string is not an integer expression.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if (( ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} < 4 )); then
    echo "Bash version 4+ is required. This is $BASH_VERSION" >&2
    exit 1
fi

letterGrade() {
    if   (( $1 >= 90 )); then echo A
    elif (( $1 >= 80 )); then echo B
    elif (( $1 >= 70 )); then echo C
    elif (( $1 >= 60 )); then echo D
    else                      echo F
    fi
}

declare -A num
while read -r score; do
    if [[ $score == +([[:digit:]]) ]]; then
        grade=$(letterGrade "$score")
        (( num[$grade]++ ))
        echo "$grade"
    else
        printf "invalid score: %q\n" "$score"
    fi
done < grades.txt

for grade in "${!num[@]}"; do
    echo "$grade: ${num[$grade]}"
done | sort
```